# fb event code unity Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>' to 'float?'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm using facebook generated code to log events in my unity app. I'm new to unity and c#. Can you help me what exactly is wrong? I have got below code from facebook [link to generate code](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/unity/#Manually%20Log%20Events).

```
public static void MyHomeVillage(string email, double datetime, bool is_login)
    {
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters["email"] = email;
        parameters["datetime"] = datetime;
        parameters["is_login"] = is_login;
        FB.LogAppEvent(
            "home_village",
            parameters
        );
    }
```

> error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>' to 'float?'

Comment: According to the documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.LogAppEvent/) the method takes 3 parameters, a string, a float and a dictionary.

Comment: yes, but above code is generated by fb itself, (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/unity/#Manually%20Log%20Events). That the reason I'm confused and also if I don't want to use the `valuesum` params it is oprional.

Comment: `valuesum` isn't optional. The dictionary is optional

Comment: As per the link, that I got from fb to generate code, `valueToSum` is like on and off switch button, so I thought it is optional.

Answer (score 1):

[`FB.LogAppEvent`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.LogAppEvent) has three arguments

> ```
> public static void LogAppEvent(string logEventName, float valueToSum, Dictionary<string, object> parameters = null);
> ```

The last one the `parameters` is **[optional](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#optional-arguments)**.

The second parameter `valueToSum` is **NOT** optional so you have to pass a `float` as second argument!

You are not passing in the mandatory `valueToSum` which is a `float`. Therefore it tries to use the given `parameters` as the second argument `valueToSum` but as the error tells you, you can't cast a `Dictionary<string, object>` to `float`.

The example generated from the link you gave us reads actually

> ```
> var softPurchaseParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
> softPurchaseParameters["mygame_purchased_item"] = storeItem;
> FB.LogAppEvent(
>   Facebook.Unity.AppEventName.SpentCredits,
>   (float)numGold,
>   softPurchaseParameters
> );
> ```

passing in a `(float)numGold` as second argument.

**NOTE: The code generator used on this webpage for `Custom Event` is broken/out-dated and does not correctly reflect the required arguments**

In order to see the correct from you have to enable the option `Use as an addition value?`

---

You could however simply use the given time like

```
public static void MyHomeVillage(string email, double datetime, bool is_login)
{
    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    parameters["email"] = email;
    parameters["datetime"] = datetime;
    parameters["is_login"] = is_login;
    FB.LogAppEvent(
        "home_village",
        (float)datetime, // <------
        parameters
    );
}
```

Or if you don't need it anyway then just pass `0`

```
    FB.LogAppEvent(
        "home_village",
        0,
        parameters
    );
```

Comment: Yes I understood it and I have solved this problem, Only thing is Facebook auto-generate code for the custom event is not updated.